# Python: Elegant way to create two different classes sharing the same definition

Tags: python, class

I need to create two tables in `peewee`. The tables are exactly the same, but one is temporary.

This is the definition of the table model:

```
class my_table(Model):
    user_id = BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Now I need to also create a temporary table `my_table_temp` which is an exact copy of `my_table`.

Yet I noticed that if I do `my_table_temp = my_table` when I do `my_table_temp.create_table()` I actually create in my database a table named `my_table`.

Is there a better way than redundantly

```
class my_table(Model):
    user_id = BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        database = db

class my_table_temp(Model):
    user_id = BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from making the temp table a subclass of original one? Like `class my_table_temp(my_table)`?
Also, please name your classes `CamelCase` in Python...

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply extend `my_table` and do nothing else,

```
class my_table(Model):
    user_id = BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = db

class my_table_temp(my_table):
    pass
```

Comment: You mean nothing else but switching to CamelCase, right?

Comment: Author of peewee -- this is what I would suggest. Just subclass your table and override anything that needs to be different (if anything).

Answer (score 2):

What about this solution?

```
def create_table():
    class TableClass(Model):
        user_id = BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
        created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
        class Meta:
            database = db

    return TableClass

myTable = create_table()
myTempTable = create_table()
```

Comment: this is the most correct answer. Only I would change function nanme to something like TableClassFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Wojciech's comment, why not use e.g.

`my_table_temp = type("my_table_temp", (my_table,), {} )`

Or if using CamelCase as recommended,

`MyTableTemp = type("MyTableTemp", (MyTable,), {} )`

For details on using `type` to dynamically create classes, see here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

or using `types`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html

Comment: NO! Just subclass. What in the world would you use `type()` for? What benefit does it gain you over simple subclassing?

Comment: @coleifer: this *is* just subclassing... it saves admittedly only 1 line of code, but apart from that it does the same thing as the class statement.

Comment: Bro I know that, it's insanely unpythonic and bad advice

Comment: @coleifer: Can I ask why you consider this to be unpythonic vs explicit subclassing without adding any functionality?

Comment: There are instances where meta programming is useful @coleifer such as generating models from somewhere else. With that said, this answer does not work correctly because attributes from my_table do not get copied over correctly. You will not have any defaults.

Comment: @JosiahL. - I just made a quick test - attributes appear to be copied across just fine, including the inner class, though I didn't test this as a subclass of `peewee`'s model - is that what causes an issue?